# Working with nested loops in python by keeping the inner list element as it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a nested loop that follows as below

```
arr = [[' item 1 ', 'item 2 ', 'item 3'], ['item 4  ', 'item 5', 'item 6'], ['item 7 ', 'item 8', 'item 9' ]]
```

I am trying to loop through the arr with 2 for loops to get rid of (strip) the spaces around each item in the inner loop. But when I use the following code, although I can get rid of the spaces, the final result only forms a combined list without the inner list elements intact.

```
clean_arr = []
for i in arr:
   for j in i:
      clean_arr.append(j.strip(' '))
```

The result I get is a single list without any inner lists/nested lists. But what I want is to keep the exact nested structure.

How can I achieve the result? Could you please put some discussion as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `list` comprehension as follows:

```
clean_arr = [[y.strip() for y in x] for x in arr]
print(clean_arr)
```

Output:

```
[['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'], ['item 4', 'item 5', 'item 6'], ['item 7', 'item 8', 'item 9']]
```

If you want to use a `for` loop, try the below code:

```
clean_arr = []
for i in arr:
    l = []
    for j in i:
        l.append(j.strip())
    clean_arr.append(l)
```